# SwiftData Error NSFileManager

Tags: ios, swift2, nsfilemanager

I'm updating [SwiftData](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData) from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2 and after some changes and corrections I'm still having an error that I can't understand why it's happening.

The code goes as the following:

```
    public static func saveUIImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {

    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let imageDirPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imageDirPath) {

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(imageDirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: [:])
        } catch {
            print("Error creating SwiftData image folder")
            return nil
        }

    }

    let imageID = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let imagePath = (imageDirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageID)
    let imageAsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    if !imageAsData!.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true) {
        print("Error saving image")
        return nil
    }
    return imageID

}
```

On the 'do {' line Xcode is throwing the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'createDirectoryAtPath' with an argument list of type '(String, withIntermediateDirectories: Bool, attributes: _, error: _)'

Any tips of why this is happening? It's driving me crazy.

Kind regards, and thanks in advance.

;)

Comment: Even though If I put the attributes set to nil the error still happens

Comment: Strange.. I don't get that error message. What is the version of your Xcode?

Comment: The latest one. Well this class has a lot of compiling errors that I'm fixing. Could this be a Xcode error since I've a lot of code to migrate to swift 2 and its detecting errors weirdly?

Comment: Yea! Try clean the project and rebuild again also resolve other issues first. That could help.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Xcode 7.2 there is no:

```
let imageDirPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")
```

So I tried this code and it compiles fine:

```
public func saveUIImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {

    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let imageDirPath = NSURL(string: docsPath)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imageDirPath!.absoluteString) {

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(imageDirPath!.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: [:])
        } catch {
            print("Error creating SwiftData image folder")
            return nil
        }

    }

    let imageID = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let imagePath = (imageDirPath!.absoluteString as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageID)
    let imageAsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    if !imageAsData!.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true) {
        print("Error saving image")
        return nil
    }
    return imageID
}
```

Comment: I have added a String extension to that, since that method isn't available on swift 2 but only in swift 1.2

Comment: `.absoluteString` will not work, because it adds the `file://` scheme prefix to the path which the API does not understand.

Comment: Hmm... Didn't thought about it. Thanks for the tip mate.

Answer (score 1):

Apple highly recommends to use the URL related API of `NSFileManager` and `NSData`

```
public func saveUIImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {

  let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  let docsURL = try! fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
  let imageDirURL = docsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")

  if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imageDirURL.path!) {
    do {
      try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(imageDirURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes:nil)
    } catch let error as NSError{
      print("Error creating SwiftData image folder", error)
      return nil
    }
  }

  let imageID = NSUUID().UUIDString
  let imageURL = imageDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageID)
  let imageAsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
  if !imageAsData!.writeToURL(imageURL, atomically: true) {
    print("Error saving image")
    return nil
  }
  return imageID
}
```